# Automated web form submission

Tags: webforms, automation, scripting

Do you know any good methodologies/tools/scripts/approaches for automated web form submission?
The form I want to operate on is NOT in my possession. That is, on any given website that's the action I'd like to perform.

Example: On http://autos.yahoo.com/ the script would choose certain value in "Make" combo box, then in "Model" combo box and then hit button 'Go'.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the data in form and then submit the form using JavaScript.

```
document.myform.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/select#fn) you could do something like this:

```
<select name="make" class="mltsel">
  <option value="acura">Acura</option>
  <option value="alfa_romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option value="am_general">Am General</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select").change(function () {
    $("#text").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000); 
  });
</script>
```

Instead of displaying some text you could do a AJAX call to get the needed information for the second selection. jQuery provides some helpful methods too - just take a look at the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice little VBScript that you can run on Windows for automation of a form submission. I used this to let a certain spammer know what I thought of his website www.reward22.com. Omit the For loop and replace with appropriate URL and variables for a single form submission.

```
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

DataToSend = "cell=800-922-
0205,password=StopTryingToStealFromPeople,pin=1234,captcha=DoTheRightThingAndShutThisPageDown"

For i = 0 to 100000
    xml.Open "POST", "http://www.reward22.com/activopopvzw.php", False
    xml.Send DataToSend
    i=i+1
Next

wscript.echo "Done!"
```